# Static filtering options in active record datatable

Tags: datatables, crud

Can someone mention some examples of static filtering options?

I also need to know what is the returned format for the count_options method in case of (start_date > 2019-11-19), how this will be returned in the hash?

https://github.com/anikolskiy/datatables_crud/blob/bootstrap_3_simple_form_rails_5/lib/datatables_crud/datatables/active_record_datatable.rb#L32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`count_options` is a method defined here https://github.com/anikolskiy/datatables_crud/blob/bootstrap_3_simple_form_rails_5/lib/datatables_crud/datatables/active_record_datatable.rb#L32

It is used internally to filter out `limit` and `offset` options. These options are used to get results for a specific page (for example for page 3 out of 10). When getting a total count of rows, `limit` and `offset` should not be used.

As for the specific example. `@options` can be:

```
{
  conditions: "start_date > '2019-11-19'",
  limit:      20,
  offset:     60,
  order:      'name ASC'
}
```

... and `count_options` will return:

```
{
  conditions: "start_date > '2019-11-19'",
  order:      'name ASC'
}
```

`order` in `count_options` is irrelevant, but also not breaking anything.

Another possible (and more common) example of `@options` is:

```
{
  conditions: { some_parent_object_id: 123 },
  limit:      20,
  offset:     120,
  order:      'start_date ASC'
}
```

and corresponding `count_options`:

```
{
  conditions: { some_parent_object_id: 123 },
  order:      'start_date ASC'
}
```